Is editing a post the only way to select a post?
Is editing a post (then saving or canceling the edit) the only way to select a post? If not, how else can one select a post?
(Example of a selected a post, which is indicated by a grey fade.)

Judging by the tags, you're not using a mouse? Keyboard only? Might want to put that in the post too then. Or remove the tag again...

@Tinkeringbell thanks, I use a mouse too. Is there a way to select using a mouse? e.g. to select a post currently visible on the screen.

Keyboard shortcuts that navigate the selection
These will move the selection to elsewhere. If nothing was selected
K - navigates to a post up. If none is selected, it selects a post at the bottom of the viewport.
J - navigates to a post down. If none is selected, it selects a post at the top of the viewport.
U - navigates to the post at the top of the page regardless of anything was selected before or not. The selection not related to where the viewport is:

in a Q&A it selects the question
in a list of posts - it select the first one

Keyboard shortcuts that do an action and select a post
These are only applicable to Q&A pages.
Some actions will automatically select a post if none is selected at first. The selection is usually the top post in the viewport but might be a bit fuzzy with partially-shownposts.
V - Vote
E - Edit
C - Add/show comments
L - Link (opens the Share link)
M - Moderate (flag/close/delete as well as access the timeline)

You can also check the keyboard shortcuts help with ? and actions that will automatically select a post are marked with *.


Thanks! Follow-up: How can one unselect a post without selecting another one or reloading/changing the page?
